# What does it mean to return an Object in C++ Code?

Tags: c++, oop

What does it mean when I am supposed to return on Object of my class in C++?

Example: **Return an EvenNumber object that represents the next even number**

Now EvenNumber is my class and I have to create a function that returns the Object of that class that stores the next even number.

```
int EvenNumber::getNext()
{
    if (evenNum % 2 == 0)
    {
        return evenNum;
    }
    else
    {
        return evenNum + 1;
    }
}
```

Now i have created an integer that returns an even number based on the users input. I dont want anyone to give me the answer but I am just not understanding the concept behind returning an object.

Clearly it looks like I am doing something wrong because I am returning an integer instead of an object in the below function.

Comment: Do you have a constructor `EvenNumber(const int& num)`?

Comment: I only have a no-arg constructor that sets number to safe empty state

Comment: Add a constructor, EvenNumber(int n): evenNum(n){} then return EvenNumber(evenNum);

Comment: Like this? if (evenNum % 2 == 0)
 {
  return EvenNumber(evenNum);
 } This gives me error "C++ no suitable conversion function from "EvenNumber" to "int" exists"

Comment: Read the comment fully, you need to provide a converting constructor for `EvenNumber` that takes an `int`.

Comment: You also need to change the return type `int EvenNumber::getNext()` to `EvenNumber EvenNumber::getNext()`, and similarly in the class body.

Comment: Is this meant to be a member of `EvenNumber`? perhaps it should be `EvenNumber getNext(int)`?

Comment: Aside: To answer the literal question in the title "What does it mean to return an Object in C++ Code?" Have a non-reference return type. `int`s are objects too

Comment: The purpose of getNext is to return an EvenNumber object so that means i need 1 argument?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To return an object of your class `EvenNumber` from `getNext`, you will need to provide a converting constructor that takes an `int`:

```
class EvenNumber {
 private:
  int evenNum = 0;
 public: 
  EvenNumber(int n) : evenNum(n) {}
  EvenNumber getNext();
}

EvenNumber EvenNumber::getNext()
{
    if (evenNum % 2 == 0)
    {
        return EvenNumber{evenNum};
    }
    else
    {
        return EvenNumber{evenNum + 1};
    }
}
```

Note that you don't need to explicitly call the constructor, since it gets called automatically, but there is no harm in being explicit.

Comment: How come when i print getNext() in main, it gives me an error. EvenNumber enterNum; cout << enterNum.getNext() << endl; So im creating EvenNumber object and i am calling getNext() from the object to get the even number

Comment: Because the compiler doesn't know how to `cout` an `EvenNumber` object. You could provide an `operator int()` that does the conversion, or you could provide an `operator<<` for your class.